# Convert multiple columns into a single column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the dataset I have:

| Employee | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Year | Index | Program | Status | Bid Category | Account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E_123456789 | #missing | #missing | #missing | #missing | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead |
| E_123456799 | #missing | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | .5 | .9 | .1 | 0 | 0 | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization |

This is what I'd like to have:

| Employee | Month | Year | Index | Program | Status | Bid Category | Account | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E_123456789 | Jul | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | #missing |
| E_123456789 | Aug | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | #missing |
| E_123456789 | Sep | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | #missing |
| E_123456789 | Oct | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | #missing |
| E_123456789 | Nov | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Dec | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Jan | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Feb | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Mar | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Apr | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | May | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456789 | Jun | FY22 | I_1234 | NA Entity | Final | Janitor 1 | Overhead | 1 |
| E_123456799 | Jul | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | #missing |
| E_123456799 | Aug | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Sep | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Oct | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Nov | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Dec | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Jan | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Feb | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | .5 |
| E_123456799 | Mar | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | .9 |
| E_123456799 | Apr | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | .1 |
| E_123456799 | May | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |
| E_123456799 | Jun | FY22 | I_1255 | P12345123 | Extended | Cook 3 | Utilization | 0 |

I found steps that seemed to do the reverse of this (convert the "Month" column into Jul/Aug/Sep/etc) but I can't find anything related to this. I am very new to Python (read: a couple weeks of use) and am sure there is a relatively easy way to do this that I just don't know.

Here is my file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('SMART_Export_Test.csv')
```

Using pivot does the opposite of what I want (it spreads the values in the Jul column into new column names):

```
data.pivot(columns = 'Jul', values='Jul')
```

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt(["Employee", "Year", "Index", "Program", "Status", "Bid Category", "Account"], 
            ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
             "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            "Percentage")

       Employee  Year   Index  ...      Account Percentage     value
0   E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Jan         1
1   E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Jan         0
2   E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Feb       1.0
3   E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Feb       0.5
4   E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Mar       1.0
5   E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Mar       0.9
6   E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Apr       1.0
7   E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Apr       0.1
8   E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        May         1
9   E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        May         0
10  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Jun         1
11  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Jun         0
12  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Jul  #missing
13  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Jul  #missing
14  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Aug  #missing
15  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Aug         0
16  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Sep  #missing
17  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Sep         0
18  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Oct  #missing
19  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Oct         0
20  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Nov         1
21  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Nov         0
22  E_123456789  FY22  I_1234  ...     Overhead        Dec         1
23  E_123456799  FY22  I_1255  ...  Utilization        Dec         0

[24 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: That was it! And even simpler than I anticipated. Thank you! And also thank you for editing the question so the tables showed up correctly.

Comment: (This thread should probably be closed as a duplicate)

Comment: Why not just a close vote instead of a comment then?

Comment: (Perhaps a prompt to consider searching for a duplicate first before writing an answer, optionally leaving a comment to OP when voting to close)

Comment: I spent many hours looking for the solution to this problem. It is difficult to search for a 'duplicate' question when I don't know exactly what to search for (hence my asking of the question).